# Javascript class variable becomes undefined with setTimeout loop despite declaring context

Tags: javascript, scope

The variable amountCompleted is set in a class because it became undefined when it was a global variable as well as when being passed into the function

amountCompleted becomes undefined after the recursive function auxReportProgress is called

How do I keep the context of amountCompleted with the following setTimeout loop?

```
function progressReport(importCount, progressID){
    this.amountCompleted = 0;
    this.importCount = importCount;
    this.progressID = progressID;
}

progressReport.prototype.auxReportProgress = function() {
    var self = this;

   if (self.amountCompleted < this.importCount) {
       var newAmount = reportProgress(this.progressID); 
           // make ajax call to get progress info

       if (newAmount){
       self.amountCompleted += newAmount;

           // indicate new amount
       }

       setTimeout(function() {self.auxReportProgress();}, 3000);

   }

}


    function reportProgress(progressID){    
        jQuery.ajax({method:'post',url:"{{=URL(r=request,f='call', args=       
        ['json','reportProgress'])}}",
                     data:{'progressID':progressID},
                     success: function(anyNewFiles){
                                    var newCompleted = 

         anyNewFiles['newCompleted'];
                                    return newCompleted.length;


                              }
         });
    }    

var progReport = new progressReport(importCount, progressID);
progReport.auxReportProgress();
```

Let me know if more info is needed. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

PV

Comment: where do you declare `importCount`

Comment: What does `reportProgress` do (and return)? How do you know that `amountCompleted` is undefined? Please provide a complete example!

Comment: `WebWorker`s are great for communicating to and from a new thread, as may be the case in a progress reporter.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @Sherali -- importCount is declared in a separate ajax call that retrieves data just uploaded.

Comment: @Felix -- amountCompleted shows to be NaN in the console after the first call to reportProgress is made.

Comment: `var newAmount = reportProgress(this.progressID); `?

Comment: @ne1410s -- Thank you for the tip

Comment: @Daniel -- It takes some time to process the data. newAmount is just to indicate whether to update a displayed flash response

Comment: @Phillip i'm confussed why you aren't calling new on that

Comment: `var newAmount = reportProgress(this.progressID);` is the problem - you cannot return the result synchronously from an ajax call, so `newAmout` is undefined here. The issue has nothing to do with your class code.

Comment: Thank you Bergi, Daniel, for pointing out this out.

Comment: @Bergi. If you post the answer, I will accept it